# Считывание данных из файла в ArrayList

Tags: java

Есть определенный файл, который представляет из себя список (товар и его цена). Этот список необходимо поместить в ArrayList. Вопрос заключается в следующем: как игнорировать данные типа string(слова) из этого файла и вносить в Array лишь цену(int или т.п.).

Это мой код, не судите строго, ведь я только учусь. (На прикрепленном изображении представлено все задание целиком для большего понимания сути вопроса)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    String path = "D:\\laba.txt";
    File file = new File(path);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        list.add(scanner.next());

        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

    }
    scanner.close();
}
}
```

[image: Задание]
[image: Пример файла]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                int a =Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine().split("- ")[1]);
                System.out.println(a);
            }
```

метод `split(String value)`  разделя строку на массив по разделители `value`

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ извлечь нужные данные - это использовать регулярные выражения.

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[а-яА-Я]+\\s-\\s(?<price>\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(scanner.next());
if (matcher.matches()) {
    int price = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("price"));
}
```

Если хотите научиться работать с регулярными выражениями - используйте сайт https://regex101.com/r/mHy4Na/1